# What service to use for Phonegap apps

Tags: android, ios, phonegap-build

I have been writing some Phonegap apps earlier and just connected them to my domain from GoDaddy etc. So I could store information in the database (PHPMyAdmin), just the basic stuff.

But for more advance apps with chat functions (NodeJS) or push notifications. There isn't that easy to do with a basic domain server, since many hosting services don't support open connection to the server as (NodeJS) etc. And running a `timeout` will load and use much more data.

What's the best service for running phonegap apps on for storing information, sending images, chat functions (real time with notifications on receive), push notifications etc.?

I have looked a little into Google Cloud Platform, and can see that many of the "professional" apps uses the service. https://cloud.google.com/

Are there other services that support these features and are better, faster, cheaper etc.?

It's easy to be lost in this ocean of services. Didn't find and good answers so thought we could list up some services, with pros and cons. So people like me could find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try google cloud messaging for receiving push notifications. It is efficient and free. [This article](http://blog.aakshay.com/2015/03/push-notifications-for-android.html) will help you register the device for that service.

After that, use the following code to send push notifications to the registered devices.

```
            string regId = "registered_ID_of_User";
            var applicationID = "Your_application_ID";

            var SENDER_ID = "yoursenderID";
            var value = Text1.Text;
            WebRequest tRequest;
            tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));

            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

             //Data_Post Format
             // string postData = "{'collapse_key' : 'demo', 'registration_id': [ '" + regId + "' ], 
              //'data': {'message': '" + Label1.Text + "'},'time_to_live' : '3' }";


            string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
                + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regId + "";


            Console.WriteLine(postData);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

            dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

            Label3.Text = sResponseFromServer; //printing response from GCM server.
            tReader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            tResponse.Close();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that! But this was more for what service to use. As in sending real-time chat messages and with push notifications (which you answered on now) and so on. Since PubNud is also er service and not easy to know what and who to go for

Comment: I had developed on HTML, C# and  MS SQL for the real time chat which was working all right. You can also look at this link for an alternate option. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27384/Build-a-Web-Chat-Application-using-ASP-Net-LIN